How to set a global variable from a bash function when its output is piped to another command
Let us define this very small bash function:
function testit() {
a=4
echo "Hello world"
}

if I run the function, then variable a will take the value 4 (which is the expected outcome):
testit ; echo $a
Hello world
4

If I unset the variable a (or start again without the variable a defined), and I pipe the output of the function to a command, the a variable won't be set:
testit | cat ; echo $a
Hello world


Why isn't the variable set to 4 in this case? Can I set the variable from the function independently if I pipe its output or not?
Thank you.

Do not name a shell function test. test is a standard utility. Replacing it with an unrelated function is a bad idea.

You are right, the name is a bad name. But the question is valid for whatever name you use. I rename the function for the shake of clarity.

Analysis
When executing a pipeline, Bash runs each part of it in a subshell. Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment. You can think of the execution environment as a shell-specific extension to the environment: it includes aliases, shell variables, shell options and more. And like the environment gets inherited by a child but the child cannot change the environment of the parent, execution environment gets inherited by a subshell but the subshell cannot change the execution environment of the main shell.
You can make Bash run the last command of a pipeline (not executed in the background) in the current shell environment, by setting the lastpipe option of shopt (shopt -s lastpipe), but this will only work if job control is turned off (set +m). Usually in an interactive shell you want job control to be on (and it is on by default).
Since you want to pipe from your function, the function cannot be the last command of a pipeline, so lastpipe cannot help you anyway.

Portable solution
You can make a named pipe, start a receiver asynchronously, run your function as a writer not in a pipeline, then wait for the receiver to finish:
#/bin/bash

testit() {
a=4
echo "Hello world"
}

fifo='/tmp/myfifo'
mkfifo -- "$fifo"
{ cat -n; sleep 2; } <"$fifo" &
testit >"$fifo"
wait
echo "$a"
rm -- "$fifo"

I used cat -n so it's clear the output comes through cat. I used sleep 2 so it's clear the shell waits for the receiver. In an interactive shell (where job control is on by default) you will get messages about the job in the background; in a script (where job control is off by default) there will be no such messages. The shebang only matters if the code is executed as a script. Note if you execute the code as a script then testit will set the variable in the shell interpreting the script, not in the shell you invoke the script from (see What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?).
The above solution is portable (well, cat -n is not portable, but it's not a part of the solution itself, just an example receiver).

Neater solution
In Bash you can use process substitution:
#/bin/bash

testit() {
a=4
echo "Hello world"
}

testit > >(cat -n; sleep 2)
wait
echo "$a"


Notes

In each of the above solutions the receiver cannot affect the execution environment of the shell. This is true even if you use a shell function instead of cat -n; sleep 2.

In general you can pipe from function to function (e.g. f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5) but at most one of them can be executed in the execution environment of the main shell. E.g. for f3 the solution is < <(f1 | f2) f3 > >(f4 | f5); wait.

If you want more than one function to affect the execution environment of the shell then you must not run them concurrently. Example:
f1 >regular_file
<regular_file f2




Conclusion
A shell function can affect the execution environment of the shell; and a shell function can be used in a pipeline. The problem is the two functionalities cannot work at the same time. In my opinion it is reasonable to design your functions (and consequently maybe even the whole workflow), so each function is supposed to do at most one of these things.

Thank you for your response. It is very good and provides a lot of bash good tips, however I still don't understand the reason, because 1) According to the bash manual, "Shell functions are executed in the current shell context; no new process is created to interpret them." (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html), even when piped. So, I don't think it is accurate talking about subshells and functions.

As an example of what I said in the previous comment, let me show you another silly example:
I define a pair of functions
test1() {echo $!} ; test2() {read j ; echo $j $!} ;
I write this shell bash and do a few pipes. It is always the same bash environment
echo -n "$! " ; test1 | test2 | test2 | test2
268284 268284 268284 268284 268284

@jicarretero "functions never run in a subshell" -- Your question shows that a function before | does run in a subshell... "Even when piped" seems to be your misinterpretation.

@jicarretero "It is always the same bash environment" – Non sequitur. The right way is to check $BASH_SUBSHELL, like this: testdepth () { echo "$1 $BASH_SUBSHELL" >/dev/tty; } and then compare the output of testdepth A, { testdepth A; }, (testdepth A), testdepth A | testdepth B, (testdepth A) | testdepth B, testdepth A > >(testdepth B); wait, testdepth A > >(testdepth B | testdepth C); wait etc. Note these A, B and C label lines of the output; this is important in cases where two or more instances of testdepth run concurrently and may print in any order.
